# How to stairplot a histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

i try to create a stairplot from an histogram, in the official documentation they reffering to **type="s"** but everytime i try to use this R just tells me that **type** is outdated but i can't find a replacement.

My script looks like this so far:

```
kg=floor(runif(100, min=140, max=201)) #Generating Data
sort(kg)
hist(kg, breaks=40)
```

[image: Resulting Histogram]

Is it still possible to create stairplots with the default hist() function?

Comment: you should use `set.seed()` when you generate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
kg=floor(runif(100, min=140, max=201)) #Generating Data
sort(kg)
h <- hist(kg, breaks=40, plot=F)
plot(h$breaks, c(h$counts, NA), type="s")
```